# How to make list accessible outside if statement?

Tags: python, sdn

I would like to access the list outside the `if` statement, is there any static   function in python?

List are `switch1Flow`, `switch2Flow` and `switch3Flow`:

Here is the code

```
def startingNode(self, destID, message, counter):
    pack =  self.pac.packet(self.name, destID, message) 
    if counter == "0":
        nextHop = self.controller.selectSwitch(self.name)
        print "Switch", self.name, "contacts controller"
        nextHop.receivePacket(pack)
        switch1Flow = [nextHop.name] //list1
        print switch1Flow
        nextHop1 = self.controller.selectSwitch(nextHop.name)
        print "Switch", nextHop.name, "contacts controller"
        nextHop1.receivePacket(pack)
        nextHop2 = self.controller.selectSwitch(nextHop1.name)
        print "Switch",nextHop1.name,"contacts controller"
        nextHop2.receivePacket(pack)
        switch2Flow = [self.name, nextHop1.name] // list2
        print switch2Flow
        switch3Flow = [nextHop.name, nextHop2.name] // list3
        print switch3Flow
    elif counter == "1":
        if 's2' in switch1Flow:
           print "forwarding to s2"
           if 's1' in switch2Flow and 's3' in switch2Flow:
             print "forwarding to s3"
             if 's2' in switch3Flow and 's4' in switch3Flow:
                 print "forwarding to s4"
                 print "message reched s4"
```

I would like to access the switch1Flow, switch2Flow and switch3Flow to be accessible in elif.Can you please suggest me how?

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36894439/edit) your post so that it makes some sense.

Comment: What should be the value of those variables in `elif` without them being initialized in `if`?

Comment: actually the list should be available and checked each time when counter is greater than zero.

Comment: is there any static function in python?? once items are added to list,can we use in elif statement

Comment: Please define what you mean by "static function" - such terms are language dependant.

Comment: when a variable is declare static in java,it takes the last updated value and doesnt change and can be accessed throughout the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the switch variables outside the `if else` condition you shall be fine:

```
def startingNode(self,destID,message,counter):
    pack =  self.pac.packet(self.name,destID,message)
    switch1Flow = []
    switch2Flow = []
    switch3Flow = []
    if counter == "0":
        nextHop = self.controller.selectSwitch(self.name)
        print "Switch",self.name,"contacts controller"
        nextHop.receivePacket(pack)
        switch1Flow = [nextHop.name] //list1
        print switch1Flow
        nextHop1 = self.controller.selectSwitch(nextHop.name)
        print "Switch",nextHop.name,"contacts controller"
        nextHop1.receivePacket(pack)
        nextHop2 = self.controller.selectSwitch(nextHop1.name)
        print "Switch",nextHop1.name,"contacts controller"
        nextHop2.receivePacket(pack)
        switch2Flow = [self.name,nextHop1.name] //list2
        print switch2Flow
        switch3Flow = [nextHop.name,nextHop2.name] //list3
        print switch3Flow
    elif counter == "1":
        if 's2' in switch1Flow:
           print "forwarding to s2"
           if 's1' in switch2Flow and 's3' in switch2Flow:
             print "forwarding to s3"
             if 's2' in switch3Flow and 's4' in switch3Flow:
                 print "forwarding to s4"
                 print "message reched s4"
```